# Можно ли вызывать функции класса из его конструктора?

Tags: c++

Можно ли вызывать функции класса из его конструктора или объект ещё не определён?

Comment: Можно вызывать, если метод не является виртуальным. А если таковым и является то необходимо явное приведение типа `Class::SomeVirtualMethod()`. Если вы попали в конструктор, значит объект уже определен.

Comment: @LLENN, виртуальные тоже можно вызывать, понимая, что делаешь. Ну и кусочек кода в Вашем комментарии это не приведение типа, это уточнение вызова.

Answer (score 3):

Хотя время жизни объекта в C++ начинается по завершении конструирования (если есть конструктор), конструктор является специальной функцией, которая в стандарте имеет свои условности ([[class.cdtor]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor)). Во время исполнения конструктора, объект находится в состоянии конструирования, и в этом состоянии можно вызывать любые функции-члены, а также виртуальные функции этого класса.

Важно понимать, что при начале исполнения тела конструктора, все конструкторы базовых классов (если есть) уже завершились, а все члены класса, которые имеют конструкторы, так же уже были сконструированы. Поэтому вызов функций-членов не может привести ни к какому непредвиденному результату. Другое дело, если вызывать функции-члены в списке инициализации конструктора — это может привести к неопределённому поведению.